# sn.exe failed on windows server 2008 r2 having both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, sign

"sn.exe -Vr *" failed due to this reason:

The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is in
correct. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.e
xe tool for more detail.

I tried to dig into more but got nowhere. My machine is windows server 2008 R2 with both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 installed. .NET 3.5's sn.exe runs well. This is blocking for me because I have to make my .NET 4.0 dlls signed to use them, which may not be easy. How can I disable strong name validation for .NET 4.0 dlls on such machines? Thanks.

Comment: maybe this helps you http://blog.davehawes.com/post/2010/10/07/Strong-name-validation-failed-on-64bit-OS.aspx

Answer (score 2):

From .NET 3.5 SP1 on strong-name validation is skipped by default when an assembly is loaded with FullTrust, e.g. from the local hard-drive (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713694.aspx).

If the validation is not by-passed you can manually register an assembly in the Registry not to be validated under the [following key](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/02/21/536260.aspx):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\My.Assembly.dll,12ba45fe33
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\*,12ba45fe33
```

Comment: Great! on 64 bit machine, I can add to HKLM\software\wow6432node\microsoft\StrongName\Verification\*,* and it seems to work.

Comment: @user527403: If you feel an answer on StackOverflow is helpful or even solving your problem, please consider upvoting the answer by clicking on the small up arrow. If it answers your question please also mark the answer as accepted using the checkmark on the left of the answer. That way others will see that your problem has been resolved and that the suggested solution is working.